# Forbidden 403 CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. drf

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

i am trying to upload image with drf:

urls.py:

```
    path('eventimageupload/<int:category>/', views.EventImageUploadView.as_view()),
```

views.py:

```
class EventImageUploadView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
      authentication_classes = []
      permission_classes = []
      def post(self, request,category):       
          file = request.data['file']            
          data={
             'image':file,
             'category_id':category,

           }
          EventsImage.objects.create(**data)
          return JsonResponse(json.dumps({'message': "Uploaded"}), status=200, safe=False)
```

its working good on localhost but from server its getting this error

Comment: did you add rest_framework to installed apps

Comment: yes its already added

Comment: you need to pass atleast one permission class, else default is isAuthenticated, to remove the csrf problem add AllowAny to the permission class

Comment: i also did this

Comment: i think i see that when i upload from localhost on postman cookies has csrf but when i test from main server cookie doesn't have csrf token

Comment: If you searched for your error message, you'd find plenty of posts on the matter. Also look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request). This just means you're not submitting the CSRF token in your ajax request.

Comment: Is your upload api called from a website (browser)?

Answer (score -1):

you need to allow cross request call

```
https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/
```

check above library, add that into your middleware

Comment: CORS has nothing to do with CSRF.

Comment: it has the middleware which by pass the csrf validation.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/ @dirkgroten

Comment: But that’s not what you explain in your answer. And why would you want to bypass csrf validation? There’s a reason we have csrf validation.

Comment: Again the fact that DRG talks about both in one page doesn’t mean they are related. They are not.